# Why do I get an import error when importing Qiskit?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, qiskit

Whenever I import qiskit, I get the following error. Anyone know why?

```
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweedledum/_tweedledum.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _aligned_alloc
  Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweedledum/_tweedledum.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweedledum/_tweedledum.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there was an issue while installing one of the Qiskit dependencies called `tweedledum`. You can try the following in your anaconda env:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tweedledum
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried that but I get the same error, unfortunately

Comment: are you getting any error when executed the suggested command?

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm able to reinstall tweedledum. Although, I fixed the issue by downgrading the module so I speculate that it might have to do with some incompatibility with my OS or something like that. Thanks for the help!